# Adding Images to Objects

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, image, object

I am working on a project where we I have an array full of objects. It stores movie information, and I would like to add an image of the poster onto the object as well. Below is an example of my code. I have functions that searches through the array for specific movies based on given information, and returns the information. I would like it to return an image with it as well. This information then gets printed onto a website. Here is the code:

```
var allMovies = [
{
    Title: "Green Book",
    Year: 2019,
    Director: "Peter Farrelly",
    Winner: "yes",
    Genre: "Biography, Comedy, Drama"
},
{
    Title: "Black Panther",
    Year: 2019,
    Director: "Ryan Coogler",
    Winner: "no",
    Genre: "Action, Sci-Fi"
},
```

and there is more code after this, but it is too long to add the whole code. Is there a way to add an image, and have it be returned with this information, and then be printed onto a page?

Comment: You can get away by storing the URL of the image. Otherwise you can consider a base64 blob or an SVG.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to what @rid said, but ill add a bit more, maybe it will help.

so your array is:

```
    var allMovies = [
    {
        Title: "Green Book",
        Year: 2019,
        Director: "Peter Farrelly",
        Winner: "yes",
        Genre: "Biography, Comedy, Drama",
        Image:"https:website.com/images/image.jpg"
    },
    {
        Title: "Black Panther",
        Year: 2019,
        Director: "Ryan Coogler",
        Winner: "no",
        Genre: "Action, Sci-Fi",
        Image:"https:website.com/images/image.jpg"
    }
    ]
```

Now you can loop through the array and use template literals to create your HTML output, it could be done like this:

```
let output='';

allMovies.forEach(Movie=>{

//we use template literals here to make things easier
output+=`<h1>Title: ${Movie.Title}</h1>
<img src="${Movie.Image}" alt="Movie Image">
<p>Year: ${Movie.Year}<p>
<p>Director: ${Movie.Director}</p>
<p>Winner: ${Movie.Winner}</p>
<p>Genre: ${Movie.Genre}</p>
`

})

const div =document.querySelector("yourdiv");

div.innerHTML=output;
```

I hope this helped :)

Comment: Well I think my problem is, that what happens if I search for the Drama genre, and 5 movies get returned but theres only one image set up in the html? Is that possible? I already have my functions set up and I use the filter to search for it. I use buttons/event listeners to return what is needed

Comment: Can you clarify a bit what you mean by " there's only one image set up in the html"?. from what i understand is that you used a function that filters the movies array based on the user selection ( so whats remaining in the array is the result that you want to display only right?) if yeah, then this implementation should be enough to do what you want, since it's dynamic and will loop through all the results and add them to the output variable, and after doing so, the data inside this output variable will be added to the html

Comment: Yes exactly, but when I tried it, it prints the actual url, and not an image

Comment: you should do something like <img src="Movie.Image">  and this should fix your problem for sure, if you don't add it inside an img tag it will just display as a text

Comment: Javascript, you cant add a property of an object directly to the html unless you are using some kind of different technologies ( which is not the case here)

Comment: you should change the last line though "yourdiv" to make it match the division in your html

Comment: check out this link: https://jsfiddle.net/mor2e4b7/ it will help you understand it more

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the url of the image.
Like this,

```
var allMovies = [ 
    { 
         Title: "Green Book", 
         Year: 2019, 
         Director: "Peter Farrelly", 
         Winner: "yes", 
         Genre: "Biography, Comedy, Drama",
         Image_url: "https://www.something.com/something/something.jpg" 
    }, 
    { 
         Title: "Black Panther", 
         Year: 2019, 
         Director: "Ryan Coogler", 
         Winner: "no", Genre: "Action, Sci-Fi",
         Image_url: "https://www.something.com/something/something.jpg"
    },
```